# Problem with the following error: Name " " is not defined

Tags: python, shapes

I am trying to do a scatter plot but I obtain the following error: "x and y must be the same size". Then, I check the size of the variables to see from where the problem comes.

However, when I do that, it seems that one of the variables (variable "pop") does not exist when it should exist.

I attach a picture of the problem:

[image]

Any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: What is pop?  I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Have you tried rerunning the cell in which pop was assigned?

Comment: @Chris "pop" is a column of my shapefile city_join. I thought is was clear, but let me know how I can give more information and I will do it.

Comment: @Zero "pop" is a column of a shapefile, how can I do that? I am a bit new in Python.

Comment: Try `city_join["pop"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined a variable named `pop`, so you can't refer to it. If it's a column of your DataFrame, you can refer to it as `city_join['pop']`

Comment: Pfff, thank you, it works. I was very stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `pop.shape` you can just write `city_join["pop"].shape`.